# Ansible - use registered variable that contains semicolon to install exact apt package

Tags: variables, ansible

I want to create a role to install latest "xx.yy" or "xx" version of a package on multiple Debian distributions.
Starting with a more generic version I use apt-cache madison, filter the results to get latest version available for that machine an register the value. I am then trying to use this value (that contains special characters) to install exact package version.

For example to install docker I use the following:

- *vars/main.yaml*

```yaml
docker_engine:
  version: 20.10
```

- *tasks/main.yaml*

```yaml
- name: Get latest docker version
  shell: "apt-cache madison docker-ce | grep {{ docker_engine.version }} | head -1 | awk '{ print $3 }'"
  register: docker_exact_version

- name: Display docker_exact_version value
  debug:
    var: docker_exact_version
  tags: debug_info

- name: Install Docker Engine
  apt:
    update_cache: yes
    name: docker-ce= {{ docker_exact_version }}
```

This fails with
Output:

```bash
ok: [...] => {
    "docker_exact_version": {
        ...
        "cmd": "apt-cache madison docker-ce | grep 20.1 | head -1 | awk '{ print $3 }'",
        "stdout": "5:20.10.18~3-0~debian-bullseye",
        ...
    }
}
...
fatal: [...]: FAILED! =>
File \"/usr/lib/python3.9/sre_parse.py\", line 598, in _parse\r\n    raise source.error(msg, len(this) + 1 + len(that))\r\nre.error: bad character range 3-0 at position 35\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}
```

If I manually introduce the version and escape the semicolon it's working fine.

```yaml
- name: Install Docker Engine
  apt:
    update_cache: yes
    name: docker-ce=5\:20.10.18~3-0~debian-bullseye
```

How can I escape semicolon when using the registered variable?

Thanks a lot

Comment: It looks like you're using the wrong output, instead try: `docker-ce={{ docker_exact_version.stdout }}`

Comment: That was it, thanks. 
Don't need to escape any character, the installed package is now "package": ["docker-ce=5:20.10.19~3-0~debian-bullseye"]